# Filtering to keep max but to ignore ties in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working in R....

I have some colleges which operate from multiple sites. We know how many students there are at each site.

```
data <- data.frame(provider_id_num = c("1", "1", "2", "3", "3"), 
                   postcode = c("S2 3EH", "S2 3ET",  "S2 34h", "S2 rty", "B1 2eh"),
                   number_students = c(1, 3, 5, 2, 2))
```

| provider_id | postcode | number_students |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S2 3EH | 1 |
| 1 | S2 3ET | 3 |
| 2 | S2 34h | 5 |
| 3 | S2 rty | 2 |
| 3 | B1 2eh | 2 |

For each provider, I want to **keep the row with the most number of students.**

However, **if there is a tie**, I  don't mind which row I keep, but **I only want it to keep only one row.**

Desired outcome:

| provider_id | postcode | number_students |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S2 3ET | 3 |
| 2 | S2 34h | 5 |
| 3 | S2 rty | 2 |

OR:

| provider_id | postcode | number_students |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S2 3ET | 3 |
| 2 | S2 34h | 5 |
| 3 | B1 2eh | 2 |

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`slice_max` sounds like it could be useful for you. Here is an [example](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html)
The example uses `slice_min`, but `with_ties` is also available for `slice_max`.

```
# Use with_ties = FALSE to return exactly n matches
mtcars %>% slice_min(cyl, n = 1, with_ties = FALSE)
#>             mpg cyl disp hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Datsun 710 22.8   4  108 93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Comment: @mvhovd --- that works perfectly on my data thanks!!

Comment: Specifically for the OP data, `data %>% slice_max(number_students, n = 1, with_ties = FALSE, by = provider_id_num)`